# How to move entire browser window to another page after clicking a button in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I've been trying to change the window url by clicking in a button of an iframe. I've tried like this with no success:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["buy"]))
    {
        echo"<script>window.frameElement.parent.location.replace('../../E.product.php');</script>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["buy"]))
    {
        echo"<script>window.top.location.href='../../E.product.php';</script>";
    }

?>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

As the window object is different within the iframe, so I guess you've to fire an event to the parent window when the button is clicked.

Say, on button click you call you call a function change location.

So to fire the event you'll write:-

```
 function responsePageLoaded(){
            var urlChangeEvent = new parent.CustomEvent('chnage:url');
            parent.dispatchEvent(urlChangeEvent);
        }
```

Now in the parent window you'll listen to the event:-

```
 window.addEventListener('chnage:url', function(e){
               // to code to chnage url
            })
```